# use lifecycle in child component in react

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I'm implementing an inherit action to archive my goal.

My goal is to call a lifecycle event in child component instead of parent one. That's what I can do in C# .net. How can I archive it? Is there any difference?

When I call lifecycle event in parent component, it works fine

Here's my code

```
class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      //......
    )
  }
}

class B extends A {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount')  // didn't log here
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate:', prevProps)  // didn't log here
  }
}
```

Thanks all

Comment: How and which component you are using? B?

Comment: yes, I want to call them in B. everything in A works fine

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sound-8hpyh here it logs

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance doesn't allow in javascript by the time I'm writing this. And life-cycle event will work only if you `extends` React.Component. So, you should not extends another component in react. The recommended way is - **use composition pattern instead of inheritance**.

```
import B from './B';

class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <B />
      //.......
    )
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount')
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate:', prevProps)
  }
}
```

Now it will work. Hope you will figure out the problem. For more please visit [reactjs composition vs inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: You're right that shouldn't use extension of components in React, but this isn't an issue of multiple inheritance. This has a single prototype chain.

Comment: because the logic in class A is very complex, so class B has to use everything in it, except for componentDidMount. anyway. I'll try your solution. Thanks

Comment: @MingHieu Got it, then you can use super class `componentDidMount` which someone answer on top.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky.

In JavaScript, a class cannot extend from multiple classes, which is also known as “multiple inheritance”. In JavaScript, objects can only be associated with a single prototype, and extending multiple classes would mean that an object associates with multiple prototypes, which is not possible.

Also, to have lifecycle methods, the  class should extend React.Component.

So you can either extend React.Component or Component A.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to use super.componentDidMount() in the child component

```
   componentDidMount() {
     super.componentDidMount();
     console.log('componentDidMount')
     }
```

here you can find the working code

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-snow-1k9t2?file=/src/App.js